# Find the size of all relevant caches when doing I/O

Tags: filesystems, io, cache, block-device

So, I'm looking at the stats from `iostat`, which updates every few seconds, and I see that I/O to device happens in bulks, say, around 40M/s, once every half a minute or so.

I'm debugging an application, which, I assume, should write in 64K blocks at a much higher rate.  So, I assume, there's some caching going on.

Thus, my question: how do I find who are the caching entities, and what is the cache size?

To remove some players from this equation: it is not filesystem, the device that is being written to doesn't have any filesystem on it.  Just a bare iSCSI disk in cloud.